# How to go from c: disk to d: - with GIT

Tags: git, windows-8.1

I start using GIT and I am still learning.

1. List items -> **ls**
2. go to folder -> **cd FolderName**

But how to go to folder on d: hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under windows you can add `/d` flag to the `cd` command:

```
cd /d d:\yourfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use git in a regular cmd DOS session (using [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) which is packaged with msysgit), in which case you would simply type:

```
d:
cd yourFolder
```

(the first `d:` is for switching to the `d:` drive)

But if you are in a git bash session, then you would path like ls `/d/yourFolder`.